# Update DynamoDB table using Lambda Function with Node.js

Tags: node.js, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update an existing DynamoDB table record that contains an ID of `0c876d54-195a-46d1-954c-80477e78e70e` and set the `status` column from `true` to `false`. I'm using a Lambda function with Node.js to perform the update. The function returns null and there seems to be little documentation to performs what should be such a simple task. Here is what I have tried:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    await updateTable().then(() => {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 201,
            body: '',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
    })
};

function updateTable() {
    const params = {
        TableName: "MyTable",
            Key: {
        "ID": "0c876d54-195a-46d1-954c-80477e78e70e"
    },
        UpdateExpression: "SET status = :status",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":status": "FALSE"
        }
    }
    return ddb.update(params).promise();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `.then().catch()` and `callback` pattern when using `async`. When you are using `async` Lambda will exit as soon as the code path is done, which will be before you hit the `.then()`.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    try {
        await updateTable();

        return {
            statusCode: 201,
            body: '',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

function updateTable() {
    const params = {
        TableName: "MyTable",
            Key: {
        "ID": "0c876d54-195a-46d1-954c-80477e78e70e"
    },
        UpdateExpression: "SET status = :status", //status is a reserved ATTRIBUTE
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":status": "FALSE"
        }
    }
    return ddb.update(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: This works. I did fix a syntax issue with the try, catch block and status is a reserved ATTRIBUTE.